# printer prints rare characters in Java using bulk transfer

Tags: java, android

I am using the following code to print a file via USB OTG to an Epson l380 printer. I have no problems connecting, even in the code I pass a pdf file into bytes and then I create it again to check that the bytes are correct.
The problem is that when the data is passed to the "bulk transfer" the printer prints the wrong symbols to the pdf document.
I attach the code and the photo of the rare symbols that this prints.

```
package com.example.test_usb;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbConstants;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbDeviceConnection;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbEndpoint;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbInterface;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import java.io.OutputStream;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;




public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private UsbManager mUsbManager;
    private UsbDevice mDevice;
    private UsbDeviceConnection mConnection;
    private UsbInterface mInterface;
    private UsbEndpoint mEndPoint;
    private PendingIntent mPermissionIntent;
    EditText TxtEntrada;
    Button BtnImprimir;
    private static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.android.example.USB_PERMISSION";
    private static Boolean forceCLaim = true;
    private byte [] ByteArray;
    HashMap<String, UsbDevice> mDeviceList;
    Iterator<UsbDevice> mDeviceIterator;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TxtEntrada = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TxtEntrada);
        BtnImprimir = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BtnImprimir);

        try{
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                mUsbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
                mDeviceList = mUsbManager.getDeviceList();
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("ERROR :",e.toString());
        }



        if (mDeviceList.size() > 0) {
            mDeviceIterator = mDeviceList.values().iterator();

            Toast.makeText(this, "Device List Size: " + String.valueOf(mDeviceList.size()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.BoxViewUSB);
            String usbDevice = "";
            while (mDeviceIterator.hasNext()) {
                UsbDevice usbDevice1 = mDeviceIterator.next();
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    usbDevice += "\n" +
                            "DeviceID: " + usbDevice1.getDeviceId() + "\n" +
                            "DeviceName: " + usbDevice1.getDeviceName() + "\n" +
                            "Protocol: " + usbDevice1.getDeviceProtocol() + "\n" +
                            "Product Name: " + usbDevice1.getProductName() + "\n" +
                            "Manufacturer Name: " + usbDevice1.getManufacturerName() + "\n" +
                            "DeviceClass: " + usbDevice1.getDeviceClass() + " - " + translateDeviceClass(usbDevice1.getDeviceClass()) + "\n" +
                            "DeviceSubClass: " + usbDevice1.getDeviceSubclass() + "\n" +
                            "VendorID: " + usbDevice1.getVendorId() + "\n" +
                            "ProductID: " + usbDevice1.getProductId() + "\n";
                }

                int interfaceCount = usbDevice1.getInterfaceCount();
                Toast.makeText(this, "INTERFACE COUNT: " + String.valueOf(interfaceCount), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                mDevice = usbDevice1;

                Toast.makeText(this, "Device is attached", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                textView.setText(usbDevice);
            }

            mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
            registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);

            mUsbManager.requestPermission(mDevice, mPermissionIntent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please attach printer via USB", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        BtnImprimir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                print(mConnection, mInterface);
            }
        });


    }

    private void print(final UsbDeviceConnection connection, final UsbInterface usbInterface) {

        if (usbInterface == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "INTERFACE IS NULL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (connection == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "CONNECTION IS NULL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (forceCLaim == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "FORCE CLAIM IS NULL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {

            connection.claimInterface(usbInterface, forceCLaim);


            try {
                //Pdf To byte
              ByteArray=  loadFile("/storage/emulated/0/Download/Prueba.pdf");

              //byte to create Pdf
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/storage/emulated/0/Download/leer.pdf");
                out.write(ByteArray);
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }




            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    byte[] cut_paper = {0x1D, 0x56, 0x41, 0x10};
                    connection.bulkTransfer(mEndPoint, ByteArray, ByteArray.length, 0);
                    connection.bulkTransfer(mEndPoint, cut_paper, cut_paper.length, 0);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "RUN PROCESS !" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
            thread.run();

        }
    }


    public static byte[] loadFile(String sourcePath) throws IOException
    {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try
        {
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(sourcePath);
            return readFully(inputStream);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (inputStream != null)
            {
                inputStream.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public static byte[] readFully(InputStream stream) throws IOException
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = stream.read(buffer)) != -1)
        {
            baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        return baos.toByteArray();
    }


    final BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action)) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                    if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
                        if (device != null) {
                            //call method to set up device communication
                            mInterface = device.getInterface(1);
                            mEndPoint = mInterface.getEndpoint(1);// 0 IN and  1 OUT to printer.
                            mConnection = mUsbManager.openDevice(device);

                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "PERMISSION DENIED FOR THIS DEVICE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };


    private String translateDeviceClass(int deviceClass) {

        switch (deviceClass) {

            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_APP_SPEC:
                return "Application specific USB class";

            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_AUDIO:
                return "USB class for audio devices";

            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_CDC_DATA:
                return "USB class for CDC devices (communications device class)";

            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_COMM:
                return "USB class for communication devices";

            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_CONTENT_SEC:
                return "USB class for content security devices";

            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_CSCID:
                return "USB class for content smart card devices";

            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_HID:
                return "USB class for human interface devices (for example, mice and keyboards)";

            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_HUB:
                return "USB class for USB hubs";

            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_MASS_STORAGE:
                return "USB class for mass storage devices";

            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_MISC:
                return "USB class for wireless miscellaneous devices";

            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_PER_INTERFACE:
                return "USB class indicating that the class is determined on a per-interface basis";

            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_PHYSICA:
                return "USB class for physical devices";

            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_PRINTER:
                return "USB class for printers";

            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_STILL_IMAGE:
                return "USB class for still image devices (digital cameras)";

            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_VENDOR_SPEC:
                return "Vendor specific USB class";

            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_VIDEO:
                return "USB class for video devices";

            case UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_WIRELESS_CONTROLLER:
                return "USB class for wireless controller devices";

            default:
                return "Unknown USB class!";
        }
    }


}
```

The photo of the wrong characters that you print is as follows.
[Rare symbols of file PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4auZu.jpg)

I need help so that this does not happen, please !

Comment: `Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "RUN PROCESS !" ,....` You cannot display a Toast in the run() of a thread. Impossible code.

Comment: ahh yes, excuse me, I had that before for testing with another loop of the thread, but please ignore that toast

Answer (score 0):

Printers don't know what a "PDF" is.

You can't just take a PDF file and dump it over USB and expect it to print.
In your case, the printer was kind enough to interpret the data as ASCII stream, so it printed parts of the PDF metadata that were in English, and the rest of the characters it matched to whatever byte values it got.

If you want to write an Android app that can print directly via USB connection you would have to do 2 huge tasks:

1. Re-implement the printer driver in Java (specific for your printer).
2. Implement a PDF rendering functionality that will "understand" the PDF document and render it to the printer using proper commands (for setting fonts, sizes, positions, and drawing graphics when needed).

This is way beyond SO, but there are a lot of resources and open source programs on the web, so good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I was thinking about it a lot, since I am new to java and I thought that sending data would solve it